# php date month from full name to short name

Tags: php, php-5.4

I have this php script

```
date('dS F Y', strtotime($dateVariable))
```

The result is this:

```
01st September 2014
```

but I need the result as this: `01st Sep 2014`

in other words, I need not the full name of the month. is that possible please?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver I just need to know what should I replace the `F` with.

Comment: @Sunand yes please write an answer to accept it

Comment: You already asked [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652614/php-how-to-change-date-to-this-format).

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent did you even bother to research this before posting the question? The manual has a **very** clear list of parameters for date...

Comment: @scrowler no I didn't. so sorry but I am in hurry to catch up the deadline

Comment: If you don't have time to do basic research to solve your problem, you shouldn't ask others to do it for free. Why not pay some programmers if you don't have time to program yourself? Reading manuals is part of programming.

Answer (score 2):

```
date('dS M Y', strtotime($dateVariable))
```

Comment: +1, but there is another guy answered first, I wish I could accept more than one answer +1

Answer (score 2):

Try as below

```
date('dS M Y', strtotime($dateVariable))
```

Comment: +1, but there is another guy answered first, I wish I could accept more than one answer +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly with the date function, using the 'M' mode.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Alternatively, check out the function JDMonthName -- using mode 2 you can get the abbreviated month name.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.jdmonthname.php

Alternatively, check out the strftime function (much like printf) for formatting your date.  The %b format gives the abbreviated month name.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: +1, but there is another guy answered first, I wish I could accept more than one answer +1